# can't find a solution to switch LI elements in IE, other browsers work

Tags: function, internet-explorer, switch-statement, html-lists

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("checking").onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("knoz").style.display = !this.checked ? null : "none";
      document.getElementById("acces").style.display = this.checked ? null : "none";
    };
  };
})();
```

```css
.selector ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checking">check me
<div class="selector">
  <ul>
    <li id="knoz" name="knoz">element knoz</li>
    <li id="acces" name="acces" style="display:none">element acces</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This function switches out 2 LI elements when the checkbox id=checking is checked.
It works perfectly in all other browsers except for internet explorer.

1 Li element has style="display: none;"
the other has style="display: block;"

```
 (function() {
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("checking").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("knoz").style.display = !this.checked ? null : "none";
        document.getElementById("acces").style.display = this.checked ? null : "none";
      };
    };
  })();
```

For all browsers the code switches out the 2 LI elements perfectly. in IE it hides the initial LI but the replacing LI doesn't show. unticking the checkbox does nothing. both elements remain hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your code as below (change the "null" to "block"):

```
<script>
    (function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("checking").onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById("knoz").style.display = !this.checked ? "block" : "none";
                document.getElementById("acces").style.display = this.checked ? "block" : "none";
            };
        };
    })();
</script>
```

Then, the result in IE browser as below:

[image]

Comment: That's it! thank you. it now works for IE browsers as well! (not yet perfect, as the page it's implemented in needs to be loaded fully before the script works but hey, it's something!)

any reasoning why it does work with "block" and not with null?